# FileUpload.SaveAs saves empty corrupted files after remove AD

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net (c# backend) application that uploads files into a specific folder on the web server via a web form using FileUpload.SaveAs. This has been working successfully until recently the Active Directory was taken down. Since then, the SaveAs creates an empty shell for the file with size zero which is corrupted. I had the AD re-installed, which did not fix the issue. The application pool that the application runs under has full access on the folder, so it shouldn't be a permissions problem, and as I mentioned this had been working perfectly for quite a while. I have a try catch around the SaveAs, but it doesn't go to the catch so there is no message, it thinks it worked. I have looked at the event viewer but there is nothing. I get the same result when testing through VisualStudio (empty file), so is there a way to get some sort of message indicating why the file won't upload correctly? This is production issue, please help!!

Frontend code:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="ButtonAtt" text="UpLoad" onclick="ButtonAtt_Click" runat="server"/>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadAtt" runat="server" BackColor="White" Width="300px"/>
```

Backend code:

```
protected void ButtonAtt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadAtt.HasFile)
    {
        //append id to filename
        string sFilename = DDFindEmp.SelectedValue.ToString() + "-" + FileUploadAtt.FileName;
        string sPath = Server.MapPath("/Training");
        // upload file into filestore directory 
        try
        {
            FileUploadAtt.SaveAs(sPath + sFilename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LabelAtt.Text = "Error uploading file: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        LabelAtt.Text = "Please select a file for upload.";
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Active Directory has *nothing at all* to do with file uploads. Post your code. The tags you posted aren't code, they don't show how you store that file. `I had the AD re-installed` random changes to core infrastructure can only *cause* problems, not fix them

Comment: That code is guaranteed to cause errors *and* lead to injection attacks. A single slash in any of the inputs will cause trouble, never mind malicious entries like `..\..`. Use Server.MapPath instead. That's what tutorials and samples for file uploading use

Comment: I have more code for file type, etc checking that has nothing to do with the SaveAs, was trying to follow the "minimal" request, and keep it minimal since the SaveAs is what is not working. The issue started when the AD was removed, I didn't remove it or know it was going to happen, so thought putting things back to the way they were may fix.

Comment: OK,  can change the mappath. But that is not the issue. The empty file is being created in the correct folder, but empty and corrupted. need help with that issue.

Comment: How large is the file? What type of file is it?

Comment: Different types of files can be uploaded. Currently just trying to upload small pdf. But this used to work . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using,

```
   while ((bytesRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
   {
       fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
   }
```

Then change it to,

```
while ((bytesRead = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
```

OR

```
context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(...);
```